# Nested filters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following nested filters in javascript but returning from the inner filter was not returning users satisfying the role I wanted so I used a different approach. Here is what I have

```
  let admins = [];
  let customers = [];

  if(users.results){
    users.results.filter(user => {
      user.roles.filter(role => {
        if(role.role.name === 'ADMIN'){
          admins.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
    users.results.filter(user => {
      user.roles.filter(role => {
        if (role.role.name === 'CUSTOMER') {
          customers.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Example of the payload is

```
{
            "addresses": [],
            "created_at": "2020-04-18 14:21:55",
            "email": "deliverypersonnel4@mail.com",
            "first_name": "Lucas",
            "id": "5c7f9e0d-4727-416c-b0ce-61bc7542aee4",
            "image": null,
            "is_active": false,
            "is_verified": false,
            "last_name": "DeliveryPersonnel",
            "phone": "2547324738723",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "role": {
                        "description": "Can only access the online shop",
                        "name": "CUSTOMER"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "role": {
                        "description": "Can only access orders for delivery",
                        "name": "DELIVERY_PERSONNEL"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "updated_at": "2020-04-18 14:21:55"
        },
        {
        "addresses": [],
        "created_at": "2020-04-18 14:20:57",
        "email": "testadmin@mail.com",
        "first_name": "Admin",
        "id": "40f32c1e-5f53-41c7-8b78-e4918b05472d",
        "image": null,
        "is_active": false,
        "is_verified": false,
        "last_name": "Test",
        "phone": "254711123456",
        "roles": [
            {
                "role": {
                    "description": "Can create, view & update all records",
                    "name": "ADMIN"
                }
            },
            {
                "role": {
                    "description": "Can only access the online shop",
                    "name": "CUSTOMER"
                }
            }
        ],
        "updated_at": "2020-04-18 14:20:57"
    }
```

How can I have the `testadmin@mail.com` in both the `admins` and `customers` array and have `deliverypersonnel4@mail.com` in the `customers` array without using the array push method.

Comment: Don't use `filter()` for side effects, it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try filter with complex condition:

```
let customers = users.filter(user => {
  return user.roles.some(role => role.role.name === 'CUSTOMER')});
let admins = users.filter(user => {
  return user.roles.some(role => role.role.name === 'ADMIN')});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what result you want. But if you don't want to use push method then you can use the given method.

```
const admins = users.filter(({roles}) => roles.some(({role: {name}}) => name === 'ADMIN'));
const customers = users.filter(({roles}) => roles.some(({role: {name}}) => name === 'CUSTOMER'));
```